# 'matrix' object has no attribute 'eigenvals'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, sympy, eigenvalue

I have the following code

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

def bra(i,d):
    arr = np.zeros((1,d))
    if i <= (d-1):
        arr[:,i] = 1
    else:
        print("Index Out of bounds")
    return arr

def density(i,j,d):
    return bra(i,d).T*bra(j,d)

SIGMA = (1/3)*(np.kron(np.kron(bra(0,3),bra(1,3)).T,np.kron(bra(0,3),bra(1,3)))+np.kron(np.kron(bra(1,3),bra(2,3)).T,np.kron(bra(1,3),bra(2,3)))+np.kron(np.kron(bra(2,3),bra(0,3)).T,np.kron(bra(2,3),bra(0,3))))

DELTA = (1/3)*(np.kron(np.kron(bra(1,3),bra(0,3)).T,np.kron(bra(1,3),bra(0,3)))+np.kron(np.kron(bra(2,3),bra(1,3)).T,np.kron(bra(2,3),bra(1,3)))+np.kron(np.kron(bra(0,3),bra(2,3)).T,np.kron(bra(0,3),bra(2,3))))
```

Essentially bra(i,d) gives a (1,d) array with (1,i)th element as one and rest as zero. For example,

```
 bra(0,3)=[[1,0,0]]
bra(1,3)=[[0,1,0]] 
bra(0,3)=[[0,0,1]]
```

density(i,j,d) returns (d,d) matrix with (i,j)th element as one rest as zero, for example,

```
 density(0,1,3) = array([[0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 0.],[0., 0., 0.]]).
```

Using the above codes, I have produced a (9,9) Matrix object by using np.kron

```
a = sp.symbols('a', positive = True)

HORO = (2/21)*(np.kron(density(0,0,3),density(0,0,3))+np.kron(density(1,0,3),density(0,1,3))+np.kron(density(0,0,3),density(2,2,3))
+np.kron(density(0,1,3),density(1,0,3))+np.kron(density(1,1,3),density(1,1,3))+np.kron(density(2,1,3),density(1,2,3))
+np.kron(density(0,2,3),density(2,0,3))+np.kron(density(1,2,3),density(2,1,3))+np.kron(density(2,2,3),density(2,2,3)))+(a/7)*SIGMA+((5-a)/7)*DELTA

M = np.asmatrix(HORO)
```

It can be shown that M matrix is invertible and it
is the following (9,9) matrix

```
matrix([[0.0952380952380952, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0.0476190476190476*a, 0, 0.0952380952380952, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0.333333333333333 - 0.0476190476190476*a, 0, 0, 0,
         0.0952380952380952, 0, 0],
        [0, 0.0952380952380952, 0,
         0.238095238095238 - 0.0476190476190476*a, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0952380952380952, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0476190476190476*a, 0, 0.0952380952380952, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0476190476190476*a, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0952380952380952, 0,
         0.238095238095238 - 0.0476190476190476*a, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0952380952380952]], dtype=object)
```

For this symbolic matrix I want to calculate the eigenvalues as

```
M.eigenvals()
```

However, it is returning the following error

```
AttributeError: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'eigenvals'
```

I can't figure out what went wrong.

Comment: What exactly is `M`?  Show us the docs for its `eigenvals` method.  In other words justify that code.

Comment: I am not sure how can I justify the code. It is written to produce an invertible matrix and I want its eigenvalues. Nonetheless, I have tried to explain bits and pieces of codes as much as possible

Comment: I'm not assking `why`.  I want you to show that an object of that class has that method.  In Python, each object class has a defined set of methods.  If you use the wrong method, or have the wrong object class, you will get this kind of `attribute` error.  You can't ask a `list` for its `keys`, as though it were a `dict`.  You can't `append` to a `dict`.

Comment: OK I'll cut to the chase.  A `sympy.Matrix` object does have a `eigenvals` method.  https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html#eigenvalues-eigenvectors-and-diagonalization.  A `np.matrix` class does not!  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html.  Don't mix and match `sympy` and `numpy` without paying close attention to their docs!

Comment: Okay. I understood, I need a sympy.matrix object. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, numpy and sympy don't mix well. Numpy can't work with sympy functions and symbols. Also, sympy tries to calculate exact symbolic solutions, which doesn't work well together with floats (sympy strongly prefers integers, rationals and symbolic expressions such as `sp.sqrt()`).

In this case, provided you don't change too much, numpy managed to calculate the matrix elements well (sums and productions are executed via the underlying standard Python).

Now, if you just use that matrix in sympy, you get:

```py
M = sp.Matrix(HORO)
print(M.eigenvals())
```

You get:

```
 {0.0952380952380952: 3,
  0.119047619047619 - 0.152455338986496 * sqrt(0.0975609756097561 * a ** 2 - 0.48780487804878 * a + 1.0): 2,
  0.152455338986496 * sqrt(0.0975609756097561 * a ** 2 - 0.48780487804878 * a + 1.0) + 0.119047619047619: 2,
  0.0476190476190476 * a: 1,
  0.333333333333333 - 0.0476190476190476 * a: 1}
```

A better approach uses `nsimplify` to convert floats to rationals:

```py
M = sp.Matrix(sp.nsimplify(HORO))
print(M.eigenvals())
```

This gives a nicer symbolic solution:

```py
{2 / 21: 3,
 5 / 42 - sqrt(4 * a ** 2 - 20 * a + 41) / 42: 2, 
 sqrt(4 * a ** 2 - 20 * a + 41) / 42 + 5 / 42: 2,
 a / 21: 1,
 1 / 3 - a / 21: 1}
```